# Database issue - how do I set up user accounts/pswds so they can ONLY add/change THEIR data?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, user-accounts, authentication

Okay... I am working to create a mobile app that allows two groups of users to do two different things.

Essentially, the goal of the project is this:

**Group A users:** create account/pswd and can enter THEIR data into the database and/or change THEIR existing data (but ONLY their data)

**Group B users:** can SEARCH the database for information that is inserted by Group A. Down the track I'd like to set it up so that they can create an user account so they can also SAVE key information to THEIR account for faster recall (so they don't have to look up the info they search for regularly) -- but that is down the track.

I have a relational database set up using the mySQL that is available with my web-hosting account (it seemed to be the easiest way to go).

I'm just trying to work out how to handle the user account creation/authentication bit, because each group should ONLY be able to CHANGE/INSERT data to their own account, but can search for information submitted by anyone else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql facilites to manage permissions: roles, users and privileges.

Navigate through mysql official documentation (i.e. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-adding-roles.html).

You can create two roles: groupA that can `INSERT/SELECT/UPDATE` one set of tables, groupB that can do the same but in another set of tables.

You can assign `INSERT` privilege in just the table you want, but `SELECT` privileges on all the tables.

Hope this info brings you some light...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this sounds like a huge project, I am sure there are frameworks out there that can do this for you. However, if you are trying to do this on your own continue reading. 
This can be done several ways. I will try to be as detailed as possible. This requires SQL as well as application development/Software engineering knowledge.

Step 1: Setup your database
You will need the following tables: All ids are primary keys auto incremented, the other fields can be varchar, except fields that have date in their name

1. sessions [id, uid, random_token, datecreated]
2. resourcescope [rid, name]
3. user [uid, first, last, email, username, salted_pwd]
4. user_type [id, name, description]
5. user_resourcescope [id, uid, rid] //lookup table between userid and resourcescope

I prefer using Java or python because you can use dependency injection or decorators. As a result, you don't have to write a lot of code when checking if a user has access.

Putting it all into practice.

```
1. When a user signs up, you save them into a user database. Depending on the user type, you give them different permissions. Next, you save the user permissions inside the user_resourcescope table.
```

You should now have the following. 
User Table

```
UID | first | last | email           | username  | salted_pwd    | usertype
 1  | james | iri  | example@isp.com | jiri1928  | klasdjf8$kljs |     1
```

UserType table

```
 usetype_id | Name
     1      | Basic users
     2      | Searcher
```

ResourceScope Table

```
   rid    | Name
    1     | FindContent
    2     | CreateContent
    3     | DeleteContent
```

User_Resourcescope

```
  id  | uid  | rid
   1  |  1   |  1
   2  |  1   |  3
```

Session

```
id  | uid  | random_token    | datecreated
 1  |  1   | ldkjfald882u3u  | 1391274870322
```

Each resource represents a request within the system. For example,

```
http://api.myapi.com/content/add - This would be associated with the ResourceScope CreateContent
http://api.myapi.com/content/delete- This would be associated with the ResourceScope CreateDelete
http://api.myapi.com/content/search - This would be associated with the ResourceScope SearchContent
```

When someone tries to create content, you check if their cred are correct by validating their session information and you check to see if they have the correct permission by checking the User_Resourcescope table.

```
To prevent users from deleting content that is not theirs. Inside the content table you can add a creator field and put the user id associated with the content. And if someone try to delete content you can check their user id against the creator field.
```